# BNF notation to SVG railroad diagram

Tags: svg, diagram, bnf

I can't find an utility or a more complete software that can translate rows of text i write in BNF into diagrams with vector formats like svg, someone can help me with this?

Comment: What would such a diagram look like?

Comment: what do you mean with that? I was looking for a railroad diagram if you mean this, but i think it's implied in the question that i made.

Comment: I didn't know what you meant either until you posted your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Googling "railroad diagram generator" quickly revealed an [online browser-based generator](http://bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) and [Clapham, an open-source generator written in Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clapham/).

Comment: the real problem is that every single solution that i found does not match my needs, especially for the svg part. I will give a try to clapham anyhow i see that it lacks in terms of documentation, i suppose i have to build it with ant.

Comment: Clapham do not works properly, apparently is only a collection of jar library with no entry point ( main ).

Comment: The entry point is in [net.hydrostatic.clapham.Clapham](http://clapham.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/clapham/trunk/src/net/hydromatic/clapham/Clapham.java?revision=23&view=markup#l125).  Check out this page for usage information: [http://clapham.hydromatic.net/](http://clapham.hydromatic.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Tabatkins' [Railroad-diagram Generator](https://github.com/tabatkins/railroad-diagrams) sounds like it'd do the business. It generates very nice looking SVG files.

[image: Railroad-diagram Generator]

However it doesn't take BNF/EBNF as an input. In which case, you'd probably want to look at [gbrault's fork](https://github.com/gbrault/railroad-diagrams) which lets you translate EBRF into SRFB grammar.